# Get the result of a stored procedure to a dataframe or Rdd?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe

How to create a data frame from the result of a stored proc?

```
  val jdbcDf = sqlContext.read.format("jdbc").options(Map(
    "driver" -> "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver",
    "url" -> jdbcSqlConn,
    "dbtable" -> "(exec aStoredProc) a" // Error
  )).load()
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not logically possible since the stored procedure can return 0 or more result-sets.

If the no of rows generated by the procedure is small the query can be executed in the driver application and the resultset can be converted into Dataframe/Dataset. 
For example the following code snippet generates the Dataframe from rw ResultSet

```
val conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://database/schema?user=username&password=pass")
val rs = conn.createStatement.executeQuery("exec stored_procedure()")
val data = Iterator.continually((rs.next(), rs)).takeWhile(_._1).map({case (_,rs) => rs.getString("col1") -> rs.getString("col2")}).toList // get the necassary columns (here I am getting col1,col2)
sc.parallelize(data).toDF()
```

Alternatively the stored procedure can be modified to write the resultset into a table and the table can be read to create a dataframe.

Comment: Can rdd be used to be filled with the result of stored procedure is avalanche? Can you give more details information about your first option?

Comment: @dc7a9163d9 updated the answer with a code example for option 1

Comment: What if no of rows generated by the procedure are not small. Is there any alternative solution to this?